# Gain block vs power amplifier

Tags: power-amplifier

I was searching for some IC to amplify a signal (like a RF frontend before an antenna) to have a stronger RF signal. I come across 2 terms and I don't really understand the difference between them. What is the difference between a gain block and a power amplifier?

Comment: They are pretty much interchangeable but when PA is used instead of power amplifier it usually means an antenna driver if you are talking transmitters.

Answer (score 2):

There is a lot of overlap in what manufacturers describe as gain blocks and power amplifiers in the +10dBm to +20dBm output region. It would be an unusual power amplifier with less than +10dBm output, and gain blocks don't often have >+20dBm output power.

As well as being lower power, gain blocks tend to emphasise good port matching and good isolation, as well as easy biassing.

Power amplifiers tend to emphasise better efficiency, even if at the cost of output match and simple biassing.

Answer (score 1):

A gain block is (generally) a voltage amplifier. Meant to drive high impedance load. A power amp is a voltage and current amplifier meant to drive a low impedance load.